# Argument of type '{ host: string | undefined; user: string | undefined ... }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ConnectionConfig'

Tags: typescript, express, mysql-connector

I'm creating a connection to an AWS mysql database like so:

```
const config = {
  host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port: 3306,
  database: process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
}

const db = mysql.createConnection(config) // config gets highlighted
```

But I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ host: string | undefined; user: string | undefined; password: string | undefined; port: number; database: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ConnectionConfig'.

Type '{ host: string | undefined; user: string | undefined; password: string | undefined; port: number; database: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ConnectionConfig'.

    Types of property 'host' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Earlier on, I had a problem with the port coming from `.env`. When I switched to hardcoding the port, I get this.

I don't understand what the problem is nor how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `process.env` is declared in `@types/node` as:

```ts
// process.d.ts
   ...
   interface ProcessEnv extends Dict<string> {}
   ...
   env: ProcessEnv

// global.d.ts
    interface Dict<T> {
        [key: string]: T | undefined;
    }
    ...
```

As you may notice the result of any lookup in `env` is `string | undefined`. While `createConnection` expects `string` at least for `host` property.

You have several options to to ensure the compiler that passed `config` is ok:

- if you're absolutely sure all env variables are correctly set just typecast your config:

```ts
type NoUndefinedField<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], undefined>;
};

createConnection(config as NoUndefinedField<typeof config>)
```

---

### Update

Quick explanation:

Here we're using `<T>` [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics) to abstract over concrete type, [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `[P in keyof T]` to iterate through all properties ([P in [`keyof T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)]) of type `T` and built-in utility type [`Exclude<>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to remove undesired types from each property of type [`T[K]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).
And after we removed all `undefined` types from the properties of [`typeof config`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) we [typecast](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `config` value to this type.

Step by step explanation:

So, we have an object (value) `config` with type:

```ts
type ConfigUndefined = {
  host: string | undefined,
  username: string | undefined,
  port: number,
}

declare const config: ConfigUndefined
```

but we need an object with another type that `mysql` create method can digest:

```ts
type Config = { // defined somewhere inside `mysql` library
  host: string,
  username: string,
  port: number,
}
```

the fastest way to ensure the compiler that **we** know better what is the type of our value in runtime is [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). We import `Config` type from the `mysql` library and assert the compiler that our `config` object has absolutely the same type as it expects:

```ts
mysql.createConnection(config as Config)
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w18dXW)

So far so good. `createConnection` is satisfied and we can stop here. Though this approach is quite brittle. What if mysql's library maintainer adds later another required property to the `Config` type? Our code still asserts the compiler that our `config: ConfigUndefined` value has *absolutely* the same type as `Config` but in fact it doesn't anymore.

```ts
declare function createConnection(config: Config): void
declare const config: ConfigUndefined

type ConfigUndefined = {
    host: string | undefined,
    username: string | undefined,
    port: number
}

type Config = {
    host: string,
    username: string,
    port: number,
    smthing: string
}

createConnection(config as Config) // ok. compiler is stil happy
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkzDW)

Well, after the runtime error we can investigate the problem, add `smthing: process.env.SMTHING` into our `config` object and we're good again. Till the next time.

Wouldn't it be better if we got that error in compile time. Without even running our code? So we cannot rely directly on the mysql's `Config` type. We should make the compiler check whether our real type is assignable (compatible) with `Config` instead. To make it work we should make the compiler to calculate the exact shape of your `config` object type *but* without those pesky `undefined` types in each property.

We should somehow iterate over each property of the type `ConfigUndefined` and remove `undefined` type if there is one.

Let's start with a simple type. `string | undefined` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). To remove `undefined` from `string | undefined` type we can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and namely their [distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) property for that:

```ts
type StringOrUndefined = string | undefined
type RemoveUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T

type StringWoUndefined = RemoveUndefined<StringOrUndefined>
// type StringWoUndefined ~ string
```

luckily we have [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) utility type in standard library that does absolutely the same for arbitrary types we want to exlude. And we can rewrite our `StringWoUndefined` type as:

```ts
type StringOrUndefined = string | undefined
type StringWoUndefined = Exclude<StringOrUndefined, undefined>
```

Now we have to iterate over `ConfigUndefined` properties and remove `undefined` from each one. Thats where [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) operator come in handy:

```ts
type ConfigWoUndefined = {
  // keyof ConfigUndefined = "host" | "username" | "port"
  [K in keyof ConfigUndefined]: Exclude<ConfigUndefined[K], undefined>
}
// type ConfigWoUndefined = {
//   host: string,
//   username: string,
//   port: number,
// }
```

Here for each `K` in `"host" | "username" | "port"` typescript calculates `ConfigUndefined[K]` [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and with the help of `Exclude` utility type removes `undefined` type from it.

Though the type looks pretty useful and if we ever want to reuse the same functionality we'll have to retype it again changing only `ConfigUndefined` to some other type we want to remove `undefined`s from. Looks kind of a good job for [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types). That's kind of a function on type-level that takes type arguments and return another modified type:

```ts
// our `old` ConfigWoUndefined
// type ConfigWoUndefined = {
//   [K in keyof ConfigUndefined]: Exclude<ConfigUndefined[K], undefined>
// }

type NoUndefinedField<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined>
}

type ConfigWoUndefined = NoUndefinedField<ConfigUndefined>
```

So far so good. But we still have a distinct object (value) `config` and type `ConfigUndefined`. And we have to keep them in sync. That's what [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) operator is for:

```ts
declare const process: { env: { [k: string]: string | undefined } }

const config = {
  host: process.env.HOST,
  username: process.env.USER,
  port: 3000,
}

type A = typeof config
// type A = {
//   host: string | undefined,
//   username: string | undefined,
//   port: number,
// }
```

And we finally can get rid of `ConfigUndefined` type.

So to sum everything up:

```ts
createConnection(config as NoUndefinedField<typeof config>)
```

Here we're getting the exact type of value `config` with `typeof config`, remove from each of its properties `undefined` type with `NonUndefinedField` and typecast our `config` value to this modified type. That makes typescript to check whether `NoUndefinedField<typeof config>` is assignable to mysql's `Config` expected type.

And though that may make sense if we're absolutely sure that all required `env`s are defined as they should. The better practice is still to use runtime checks to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the types. Just as it is done below in assertion function.

---

- implement proper [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) for config:

```ts
function assertConfig<T>(config: T): asserts config is NoUndefinedField<T> {
  for (const key in config) {
    if (typeof config[key] === 'undefined') 
      throw new Error(`Config check failed. Key "${key}" is undefined.`)
  }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mA7ePw)

- implement custom [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or use other [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) technics to exclude `undefined` values

Though, I believe for production code assertion function is the proper way to exit early on database misconfiguration.